# Why do specific green colors appear darker when using a dedicated GPU? (RX580)

Tags: graphics-card, colors, amd-graphics-card

I recently upgraded my graphics card to a RX580 (Polaris 20 XTX) but now I have been noticing weird problems with specific colors. I first noticed it when looking at the Spotify logo but now I see that it makes a range of green-blue colors appear darker than they are.

If you look at the top right of the color picker the colors are very off and I'm not sure what is causing this. My monitor is pretty old but I don't remember seeing this with just the integrated graphics (I tried switching to only integrated graphics just to be sure, but my BIOS was being tricky and not cooperating).

##### By the way, taking a screenshot of the glitched colors and then sending that to my phone shows no problem at all, so I guess that means the problem is with my monitor instead? (Nevermind; see below, this is likely not the case)

My PC Specs (all info from HWiNFO):

- CPU: Intel Core i3-9100
- Motherboard: ASUS PRIME H310I-PLUS R2.0
- GPU: AMD Radeon RX 580 (Polaris 20 XTX) [Pine Technology] *(NOTE: I think this is the Black Edition which means it is factory overclocked, but I doubt this would be the source of the problem)*
- SSD: CT120BX500SSD1 [120GB] *(NOTE: My disk space is running very low but I am planning on upgrading soon and I also don't see why that would affect the colors)*
- RAM: DDR4-2400 / PC4-19200 DDR4 SDRAM UDIMM, Crucial Technology CT8G4DFS824A.C8 *(NOTE: the rest of the model number is cut off)*
- Monitor: DELL P2412H (Analog)
- WiFi: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz

##### After unplugging the GPU and testing the HDMI to VGA adapter I was using, I confirmed the issue didn't appear when using the integrated graphics (even with the adapter), so the issue must lie in the GPU itself and not my monitor. See image below.

[image]
Using integrated graphics (looks the same with and without adapter)

[image]
With Dedicated GPU

[image]
With Dedicated GPU

[image]
With Dedicated GPU

[image]
With Dedicated GPU

More examples can be [found here](https://imgur.com/a/5c3pqpv).

Link to [example video](https://imgur.com/a/nf7Nh0x).

##### (Only the darkened color at the very top right appears in real life; the weird flicker in the middle is just a video artifact):

[image: Monitor HWiNFO]

#### It turns out the problem can be fixed temporarily by running DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) and then installing the AMD Drivers from their site. (I searched for the drivers instead of using the automatic installer this time, I'm not sure if that changed anything.) But, the issue reappears after using my computer for a while.

Answer (score 0):

First; check your monitor cable for any nicks, kinks or other anomalies from being straight, round, nice. If cable is seemingly OK...

Old display, old electronics - https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/f2e7756

Old electronics may get "sick" and get into the habit of doing strange things.

Here it seems as the received (stated Analog) signal for green color is causing the electronics to falter at a specific higher value.

One might speculate that the "FRC" function is failing for the green channel (ref: link above).

Looking at the electronics inside the display; it might be as simple as an old solder joint needing to be resoldered.
But to find the problem you need to get your eyes directly on it, or find it with the help of e.g. a DVM, Oscillocope and the schematics and component location diagram from the producer (= fairly advanced electronics fault finding)

Comment: I tested the integrated graphics by removing the GPU and eliminated the monitor and HDMI to VGA adapter cable from causing the issue. I'm 99% sure it must be from the GPU. (See my updated question for more information).

Comment: Well, remote fault finding is always hard, so your findings may well be as good as mine :-)